# Django - Temporarily save request token for OAuth 1.0a flow

Tags: django, oauth, oauth-1.0a

The Twitter OAuth 1.0a flow requires `authenticated request token` to be exchanged with `access token` at `consumer or client` side after `user` has authenticated.

The problem that I'm facing is that generating `access token` needs `authenticated request token`, `request token secret` and `verifier` but the response from the `oauth/authentication` api doesn't have `request token secret`. So how do I temporarily save request token secret from `oauth/request_token` api call so that I can use it in `oauth/access_token` api call.

I found some solutions from my explorations like Running a Cache server (**Memcached, Redis**) or using **django session** feature. But they all seem to be overkill for this task.

I hope to find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you long ago figured this out, but just for future goolers: I decided to a go a more low tech route and create an OAuth token class which includes fields for the fetched and access token. Basically I take the fetched token, store it, then recall it when accessing (as it's in a different view) and then save the access token. Once (if) that's successful than I delete the fetched token.

There's likely a more glamorous way to do this, but if you're clever with your naming convention you can easily keep them straight (i.e. add a CharField for provider and just save the fetched token as twitter_fetched, and the access token as just twitter).

This has the added benefit of allowing you to create an OAuth1 or OAuth1Session from the stored access token.